# How can I retrieve rows by with the latest date by using Google SpreadSheet API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a big Google SpreadSheet document that stores some data and I need to use [Google SpreadSheet REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) to retrieve particular rows from it.

Let's say we have the following test data:

```
ID | Name | Date
-----------------
1  | Erik | 07.06.2017
2  | Anna | 07.06.2017
3  | Kirk | 07.06.2017
4  | Erik | 06.06.2017
5  | Anna | 06.06.2017
6  | Kirk | 06.06.2017
....
```

I need to retrieve rows with the latest date such as:

```
1  | Erik | 07.06.2017
2  | Anna | 07.06.2017
3  | Kirk | 07.06.2017
```

How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT:**

From the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range) I've found that I can retrieve a range by the following request:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5
```

But this not suitable for me because I need filtering by max date :(

Comment: can you filter it on a different sheet? then use the REST

Comment: Unfortunately this is read-only public document and I don't have permissions for editing it.

Comment: Well, Google Sheets are not meant to be a database. How about fetching all data, then using array.filter() with a comparator function as an argument to create another array with the values you need?

Comment: You could also create a standalone GAS file that will serve as an API for this particular sheet and define all data processing functions there  alongside doGet() and doPost()

Comment: @AntonDementiev thanks for the suggestion. The first approach may be a bottleneck for my server because as I said the document is very huge. The second approach looks interesting for me and it seems there are no other ways to solve my problem. Thanks for the answer

Comment: hey @Erik did you get the chance to see my GAS script, I think that could help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use event object that tracks every change in sheet to track last modified and 'copy' it to some fixed possiion in sheet like I did in this short video..

[image: my example sheet and data that is last modified]

you have to paste this in your `Tools -> Script Editor`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rng = e.range;
  var ix = rng.getRow();
  var X = s.getRange( ix, 1, 1, 3 );
  s.getRange( 3, 5, 1, 3 ).copyTo( s.getRange( 4, 5 ) ); // SECOND LAST TO BUTTOM
  s.getRange( 2, 5, 1, 3 ).copyTo( s.getRange( 3, 5 ) ); // SECOND LAST TO BUTTOM
  X.copyTo( s.getRange( 2, 5 ) ); // LAST ON TOP!  
}
```

.. and then you can pull your data via REST like:

GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!E2:G4

hope that helps :)

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. Thanks for the script. I've came up with the similar solution. Your post was very helpful for me really :)